# How does the Tarski axiom relate to the Grothendieck universe?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, foundations

It's claimed, e.g. in the formulation of [Tarski–Grothendieck set theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%E2%80%93Grothendieck_set_theory), that the [Tarski axiom](http://planetmath.org/tarskisaxiom) implies that for every set, there is a [Grothendieck universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_universe) containing it.

However, I can't see how the Tarski axiom implies that the set which is being constructed is e.g. transitive. If $x$ is the set generating $U$ via the Tarski axiom and $x=\{y\}$. How do I show that $y\in U$? None of the points in Tarskis definition put elements of $x$ directly into $U$, only sets containing these.

If we need some of the other axioms to do it, how?

Comment: This axiom is adopted on Mizar proof checker; by I can't find a proof of this fact.

Comment: @FabioLucchini: Yeah, in fact I've writen parts of the Wikipedia article on Tarski–Grothendieck set theory and its Mizar motivations. I can't believe 3 years passed.

Comment: Probably, the Tarski's axiom must to be modified: For every set x, there exists a set y whose members include:
- x itself;

- every *member* of every member of y;

- the power set of every member of y;

- every subset of y of cardinality less than that of y.